# Euclidean LQCD not on a lattice?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, computational-physics, simulations, quantum-chromodynamics, lattice-gauge-theory

How much the idea of calculating Euclidean path integrals in LQCD is fundamentally tied to using formulations based on the discretized spacetime lattice?

In computational approaches to quantum many-body physics relying on real-time Hamiltonian formulations (quantum chemistry, low-energy nuclear physics, light-front quantization), one oftentimes discretizes the real space using various basis sets (Gaussians, oscillator eigenfunctions, etc.). This, *inter alia*, allows one to avoid the fermionic sign problem and to use bases highly-optimized for studying localized bound states. (Of course, this comes at the price of complicating the form of interactions.)

Note that my question is not about smth like Kogut-Susskind, i.e., Hamiltonian LGT. I am asking whether Lagrangian LQCD can be done not on a spacetime lattice but using some other discretization.

Answer (score 2):

The lattice is just a regulator, and is not intrinsic to studying Euclidean quantum field theories whatsoever. Most regulators that work in Minkowski-time QFTs will also regulate the Euclidean QFT, for example you can compute Euclidean correlation functions and so on by Dimensionally Regulating the Euclidean theory.

The lattice is nice regulator because it provides a way to numerically determine features of the theory *nonperturbatively*. I'm not aware of any real alternatives in the case of QCD, but some ideas that may or may not be interesting to you:

- [Random lattices](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0550321382901237) have been studied. As the random lattices are also averaged over, in some sense this is distinct from regular lattice-QCD. Of course, you could also think about doing lattice-QCD with some fixed non-hypercubic lattice, but people like the hypercubic lattices because they are easy to code up and they preserve a large finite subgroup of the continuum symmetry.
- Lattice-QCD is most similar to hard-cutoff regulators, such as in the Wilsonian picture, where there is some $\Lambda_\mathrm{UV}$ for which all modes higher than this cutoff are removed from the theory. My impression is that this type of regulator is difficult in practice to compute with, but is quite similar in style to lattice-QCD, where $\Lambda_\mathrm{UV} \sim a^{-1}$ where $a$ is the lattice spacing.
- Another `regulator' in the same vein is [Wilson-Flow](https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.4518). I'm not an expert, but I don't think this qualifies as a complete regulator as the fields and gauge coupling still have divergences, but if I understand the divergences in composite operators are all removed at fixed positive flow time. Similar to the other dimensionful regulators above, where fields are smeared in some characteristic smearing radius $\sqrt{t}$.